# How to align an embedded map to the center?

Tags: html, css

I am working with HTML code in Virtual Studio Code
I am trying to align an embedded map to the center, how can I do it?
This is my HMTML code below

```
<section class="s1">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1167.5294152864003!2d-61.68113627762967!3d10.173743187947649!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8c35981ef58b6ff1%3A0x2860fb17b3f419ea!2sNP%20Gas%20Station!5e0!3m2!1sen!2stt!4v1652554264724!5m2!1sen!2stt" width="800" height="400" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>

    
</section>
```

This is my CSS code below

```
.s1{align-self: center;}
```

Does anyone have any recommendations for amending the CSS code?
I have also tried

```
.s1{align: center;}
.s1{align-item: center;}
.s1{padding-left: auto; padding-right:auto;)
```

but these codes are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need can be easily achieved by using flexbox, here is the css you need, Hope it helps

```
.s1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center;
    height: 100vh; */   /*  uncomment these two lines   if you want to center vertically also */
  }
```

Comment: You're wellcome, please mark the answer correct , click on the check mark near my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`align-self` only works in flex.

(Note: if you are looking for horizontal, use `justify-self`)

[align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) [justify-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self)

Example:

```css
.s1 {
  align-self: center;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <section class="s1">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1167.5294152864003!2d-61.68113627762967!3d10.173743187947649!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8c35981ef58b6ff1%3A0x2860fb17b3f419ea!2sNP%20Gas%20Station!5e0!3m2!1sen!2stt!4v1652554264724!5m2!1sen!2stt"
      width="800" height="400" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>


  </section>
</div>
```